What is the replacement for the deprecated @MockBeans in SpringBoot 3.4.0?
We defined an annotation for our tests to avoid to declare Mockito Mocks for all the test classes.
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@MockBeans({
        @MockBean(ServiceA.class), @MockBean(ServiceB.class), @MockBean(ServiceC.class)
})
public @interface MyMocksTest {

}

This was perfectly OK since we don't need to declare any behavior for our mocked Service. We just want them to be mocked.
Since SpringBoot 3.4.0, @MockBean and @MockBeans are deprecated and both indicates to use the new @MockitoBean annotation. But the new annotation cannot be used on types and there is no @MockitoBeans annotation.
I don't want to declare all mocks as beans in every classes, since the above list is just for an example, but we have actually more than 20 mocks defined.
How to get the same behavior without using the deprecated @MockBeans annotation?

At the moment you don't. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/33925

@M.Deinum Thank you for the issue. This is exactly the same problem.

At the moment you don't but it is on the list. See also this related issue and a Spring Boot documentation request
So for the time being use the deprecated annotations, they won't be removed until 3.5/4.0 I expect so for now it will keep working.

It is very confusing, just marking it as Deprecated.

Viewing the JavaDocks for @MockBean, it states to use @MockitoBean
For me it was a simple replace of the Annotation.

You did not read the question. The question is about MockBeans and not MockBean.
